# Communicate to Android App via Rails Server- send data from app to server?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, tcp, push-notification

I have a Ruby on Rails app running which has a database of telephone numbers. I need to run apps on 5 different phones such that they get a notification from the Rails server with a phone number (this is done one after the other, not all phones get the number together). On receiving the phone number, the app checks if there is an existing call or not. If there is no call, it dials the number otherwise sends a 'Phone Busy' status back to the Rails server.

I was thinking of ways to do this. I figured out the App part of it: I start a new Activity with the Call Intent and have the appropriate permissions set in my manifest file, I also can check status using the Telephony Manager.

But I am not able to figure out the communication part. I first thought of a push notification using GCM and then I even read about an independent TCP connection from my server to my app.

My question is: I am not able to get clear on whether it is MANDATORY to use GCM or I can work around it with real time communication? If yes, how?

PS: As soon as the phone number is added to the DB on the server I want a notification sent. In real time.

**EDIT 22/03/13:**

So I tried GCM and built my Android App and the Rails server. I am able to send push notifications in almost real time using 'gcm' gem.

I need to figure out the response from the app part. I need to acknowledge the number with a call success/fail notification. How can I do that over GCM, if I can?

Comment: PS: As soon as the phone number is added to the DB on the server I want a notification sent. In real time.  for this i would suggest push notification "Android GCM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Google Cloud Messaging. Its not completely reliable and does not work well with certain Android phones, however, I found a phone for which it works and for my use case it all fit in.

I push a number to the app via GCM and then the app makes a call using the dial intent. Also when dialing it also updates the phone's and call's status on the server via an async post. I implemented a PhoneStateListener for this.

Also on using the 'gcm' gem from github I realized that the responses of the gcm message are not correct. Many a times, it says that the response is 'success' even though message is not delivered. This is another reason why GCM is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question. Why can't you simply create a event for adding number and call a API of ROR and sent success/fail notification status.

If you want to add it in database , that good , if you want to add a notification on Web based Interface that's a different story altogether. Use Web Sockets or Socket IO